# Using an existing `.toc` file as source for table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to split a working LaTeX document (book class) in two volumes, keeping in each volume exactly the same Table of Contents of the original whole document. Of course I also plan to keep the page numbering of the second volume as the continuation of the first volume. If I just copy the `whole_doc.toc` file of the original whole document and rename it as `volume1_doc.toc`, as expected the ToC disappears after first compile and gets updated after additional compilations.

How can I insert the ToC telling LaTeX to use the existing `.toc` file without updating/rebuilding the Table of Contents?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can simply input it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer After deleting the first line (`\babel@toc {english}{}`) from `whole_doc.toc` and replacing `\tableofcontents` with `\chapter{Table of Contents}`plus `\input{whole_doc.toc}`, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.